# How to test async in react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I'm using `async` to fetch the data from an API. Code is given below

```js
import React from 'react';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'

import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

// Chart
import Chart from "react-google-charts";

// async
import { useAsync } from 'react-async';

const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
const API_URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=bengaluru&appid=${API_KEY}`;

const loadUsers = async () =>
  // That is weather API which pulls Bangalore's 5 day weather data.
  await fetch(API_URL)
    .then(res => (res.ok ? res : Promise.reject(res)))
    .then(res => res.json())

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  customPos: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(5)
  },
  gridPos: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(5),
  }
}));

export default function Dashboard() {

  const { data, error, isLoading } = useAsync(
    {
      promiseFn: loadUsers
    }
  )
  const classes = useStyles();
  if (isLoading) return "Loading..."
  if (error) return `Something went wrong: ${error.message}`
  // console.log("Data is", data)
  // Pulling temparature data
  const mapped = data.list.map(d => [d.main.temp_min, d.main.temp_max]);
  const chartData = [["Time", "Temperature"], ...mapped];
  // Pulling humidity data
  const map = data.list.map(dt => [dt.main.humidity]);
  const pulledData = [["Humidity"], ...map];
  // Pulling weather and wind data
  const mp = data.list.map(dat => [dat.weather.main, dat.wind.speed, dat.wind.deg, dat.clouds.all]);
  const pulledcomboData = [["Status", "Speed", "Degree", "Clouds"], ...mp];
  // Pulling overall details
  const columns = ["Date and Time", "Wind Speed", "Ground Level Pressure", "Sea Level Pressure", "Humidity", "Temparature"];
  const tableData = data.list.map(tabled => [tabled.dt_txt, tabled.wind.speed, tabled.main.grnd_level, tabled.main.sea_level, tabled.main.humidity, tabled.main.temp]);
  // console.log("Table data is", tableData);
  const options = {
    filterType: 'checkbox',
  };

  if (data)

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <div className={classes.customPos}>
            <h3>Weather Details</h3>
          </div>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography className={classes.title} gutterBottom>
                    Temparature Data:
                                    </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="body2" component={'span'}>
                    <Chart
                      chartType="BarChart"
                      data={chartData}
                      loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
                      options={{
                        chartArea: {
                          width: '50%',
                          height: '50%'
                        },
                        hAxis: {
                          title: 'Maximum Temparature',
                        },
                        vAxis: {
                          title: 'Minimum Temprature',
                        },
                      }}
                    />
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography className={classes.title} gutterBottom>
                    Humidity Histogram:
                                    </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="body2" component={'span'}>
                    <Chart
                      chartType="Histogram"
                      data={pulledData}
                      loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
                      options={{
                        seriesType: 'bars',
                        series: { 5: { type: 'line' } },
                      }}
                    />
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography className={classes.title} gutterBottom>
                    Wind Data History:
                                    </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="body2" component={'span'}>
                    <Chart
                      chartType="BubbleChart"
                      loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
                      data={pulledcomboData}
                      options={{
                        chartArea: {
                          width: '50%',
                          height: '50%'
                        },
                        bubble: { textStyle: { fontSize: 11 } },
                      }}
                    />
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <MUIDataTable
                title={"Overall data"}
                data={tableData}
                columns={columns}
                options={options}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Is it enough if I `mock` the async call? Is it enough if I test if my `method` was called?

Comment: It depdends on what you want to test, both options are valid. You can also look at helpers libraries like `fetch-mock-jest` (or just fetch-mock if not using jest)

Comment: Hmm... I was looking at this just now... https://codereviewvideos.com/course/react-redux-and-redux-saga-with-symfony-3/video/testing-javascript-s-fetch-with-jest-happy-path